# How can i perform explicit wait for elements inside a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to come up with a script that clicks multiple elements on a page. I've created a for loop to try and loop through the elements clicking them all. However when the loop tries to click the following element i got the error (The element is stale)

I've tried using an explicit wait for element, but have yet to figure how to put it to work

```py
for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('marginright5.link.linkWithHash.detailsLink'):

        i.click().WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((i))
        driver.back()
```

Hopefully you can help me figure out what went wrong with my code. Using it like this i get a syntax error, not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

It seem like you need combination between `element_to_be_clickable` with `invisibility_of_element_located`.

So after you click each element you need make sure the element invisible then you can call `driver.back`.

```
for i in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('marginright5.link.linkWithHash.detailsLink'):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(i))
    i.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(i))
    driver.back()
```

Comment: `marginright5.link.linkWithHash.detailsLink` doesn't looks like a `class_name` but a `css_selector`

Comment: @DebanjanB you're right, the user should make sure use correct locator for use the above way.

Comment: Else your analysis and the effort to construct the canonical answers goes in vain.